# jQuery set checkbox value to URL & get the value in PHP to be an array & query it using NOT IN

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this multiple checbox below

[image]

And you can see PDF image there, I set it to be link

```
<a class="openPO" id="<?php echo $dData['po_no']; ?>"><img src="../assets/img/pdf.png"/></a>
```

And now I'm using jQuery to get uncheck checbox and set it to URL value.

```
$('.openPO').on('click', function()
{
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');

    var final = '';

    $('.chkPrint'+ID+':not(:checked)').each(function(){        
        var values = $(this).val();
        final += values;
    });

    alert(final);

    $("#"+ID).attr("href", "openPO?po_no="+ID+"&chkPrint="+final);
});
```

Result of set URL

```
http://localhost/nok/PRO/openPO?po_no=BP180300001&chkPrint=RQ201803000003RQ201803000004
```

What I want is:

Now on PHP, I want to get the chkPrint to be array and set it to query

```
SELECT * FROM tb_pro_request WHERE requestid NOT IN('$chkPrint');
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append a character which won't appear in the PR No. while building the final variable. ex,

```
final += (final != '' ? ',' : '') + values;
```

Then, url will be

```
http://localhost/nok/PRO/openPO?po_no=BP180300001&chkPrint=RQ20180300000,3RQ201803000004
```

explode and implode `$chkPrint` variable, ex,

```
"SELECT * FROM tb_pro_request WHERE requestid NOT IN('".implode("','",explode(",",$chkPrint))."')";
```

Comment: Just not tried only work if 1 checkbox uncheck. If more than 1 checkbox uncheck not working. When I try to echoing `$chkPrint`, get result like this: `RQ201803000001'RQ201803000003`

Comment: I missed 2 chars `,'` in the implode. I update the the Answer. Please try this one...